# Trying to convert python token generator to java

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to convert a python function to Java and I seem to be having some issues with the generated results. It may be my approach I'm not sure, but I think I've converted it properly, but the return values are not the same.

**The Python Code**

```
def __token(d):
    try:
        token = 857

        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            n = 0

            k = 'location' + k

            for i in range(len(k)):
                n += ord(v[i]) if i < len(v) else 0
                n += ord(k[i]) if i < len(k) else 0

            n = hex(n)[2:]
            i = 0

            for e in range(len(n)):
                i += ord(n[e])

            token += i

        return token

    except Exception:
        return
```

**The Java Code**

```
private long token(final Map<String, String> data)
{
    long token = 857;

    for (final String key : data.keySet())
    {
        int n = 0;

        final String k = "location" + key;
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length(); i++)
        {
            n+= (i < data.get(key).length()) ? (int) data.get(key).toCharArray()[i] : 0;
            n+= (i < k.length()) ? (int) k.toCharArray()[i] : 0;
        }

        final String subN = Integer.toHexString(n).substring(2);
        int i = 0;

        for (int e = 0; e < subN.length(); e++)
        {
            i += (int) subN.toCharArray()[e];
        }

        token += i;
    }

    return token;
```

When I execute the python code with the following:

```
token = str(__token({'id': 'o89jqj', 'update': '0', 'ts': '1503414000'}))
```

I get the result: **1417**

When I execute my java code with the following:

```
final Map<String, String> tokenMap = new HashMap<>();
tokenMap.put("id", "o89jqj");
tokenMap.put("update", "0");
tokenMap.put("ts", "1503414000");

final String token = String.valueOf(token(tokenMap));
```

I get the result **1104**

Any help would be a godsend. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`hex()` returns something like `0xF1` (so `[2:]` is needed), while `Integer.toHexString()` returns something like `F1` (so subscripting is not needed).

For such cases of program-to-program translation I would recommend just to choose a simple input (in this case, a dictionary/map with a single element, since element order may differ) and run the programs in two debuggers, comparing values of variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and clarification on hex to string.